# Cannot Install Pagegen (pagegen.conf, Not found)

Tags: python, macos, static, generator

I am trying in vain to install a static web site generator, Pagegen, in OSX (Mac), and I've followed the instructions [here](http://pagegen.phnd.net/user-manual/installation) to the letter.

The problem I'm encountering is that it suddenly cannot find 'pagegen.conf'.  More specifically, after attempting to "test" the installation with the following command (the rest of which is found on the above link):

```
$ <path to pagegen>/pagegen --init --pagegen-conf <path to pagegen.conf>
```

I get the following error:

```
Error:  pagegen.conf, not found in current, ~/.config/ or /etc/ directories
```

Can somebody please tell me what's going on here? As always with open-source projects, my patience is running thin.  Did I not copy and paste the commands correctly?  Did I put in the wrong path?

Again, here are the instructions to "test" this installation copy and pasted from the website above:

```
$ mkdir my_site
$ cd my_site
$ <path to pagegen>/pagegen --init --pagegen-conf <path to pagegen.conf>
$ echo -e "base_url=file://$PWD/site" > site.conf
$ <path to pagegen>/pagegen --generate
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

pagegen.conf tells pagegen where things are, it contains two settings:

```
skel_dir=[path to pagegen skel dir]
lib_dir=[path to pagegen library, optional]
```

It can be located in the current working directory, ~/.config/pagegen.conf or /etc/pagegen.conf

Hope that gets it working.